# How can I read lines of a file into an array then search for matching keywords?

Tags: java

I would like to read a file and store the lines in an array, then use a **JOptionPane** to search the array and display all lines which match a specified keyword.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class NeedleInHaystack {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg", "gif","txt");
    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnCode = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnCode == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION); 
    File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
       System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +jfc.getSelectedFile().getName());

    try {
        BufferedReader data;
        String aLine;
        data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jfc.getSelectedFile()));
         List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

         String UserInPut= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word in your txt");

            while((aLine = data.readLine()) != null){
                lines.add(aLine);                               
            }
             String[] stringArr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
             for(int i=0 ; i < stringArr.length; i++){

            System.out.println(aLine);

            if (i<=15) {      //here just a example, how to do this step
                i++;
                System.out.println(stringArr[0]);
            }
             }
             data.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg", "gif", "txt");
    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnCode = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnCode == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        ;
    File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + jfc.getSelectedFile().getName());

    try {
        BufferedReader data;
        String aLine;
        data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jfc.getSelectedFile()));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        String UserInPut = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word in your txt");

        while ((aLine = data.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(aLine);
             // !!!Output userunput and line of file!!!
                            if (aLine.contains(UserInPut)) {
                System.out.println(UserInPut + " -> " + aLine);
            }

        }

        data.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: but I need enter a word. Then display some line with the word, like I enter a "at". it will display    "3. so leave a message at the tone "   and      "5. uh I'm gonna kick my feet up and stare at the fan"   the two lines what include "at", can you help me do that?

Comment: @OwenZ94, have you tested this code? It does exactly what you say you want it to do. I ran it and output looks like this: `at -> 3. so leave a message at the tone
at -> 5. uh I'm gonna kick my feet up and stare at the fan
at -> 7. to stand at the door`

Comment: thank you so much, First time I tested this , i missed something. I got it. Thank you so much

Comment: I also want to do like display the line like this "  3:  3. so leave a message at the tone"  "5: 5. uh I'm gonna kick my feet up and stare at the fan at"   the number before the line like " 3: "  When it run, it will display the line of number. how to do that?